# Establishing Parent-Child Relationship via Process Builder

Tags: data-loader, process-builder, relationships, externalid

Here is my use case:

A data load of applicant information must be inserted (no updates) into Salesforce. From this applicant information, a Contact record must be created with a specific record type and a child Applicant record related to the Contact record. An Application ID exists that can be used to relate the two records together as an external ID. While the two records share some of the same fields and values (name, email, phone, etc.), the vast majority of the information will be populated on the Application record rather than the Contact record.

Is this possible to do via the Process Builder and a single data load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `Process Builder` if you want to store *every* data point on the `Contact` record somewhere. Perhaps you could load the data into dummy fields and then, after you create the child record based on that data, clear them out, but I would not recommend it. Among other issues, you may have irrelevant validations applied to the data that don't make sense, and `Process Builder` runs after those fire.

If this is a one time data load, there is no question using `Process Builder` is going to be more effort than it is worth. If you plan on doing the data load multiple times, you should just do it as two separate operations each time. I'm pretty sure you can just leave columns unmapped for the object you're not loading. At least with [dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io), you shouldn't have any trouble using the same csv for both loads.

Comment: I had a feeling this was going to be the right answer. As a consultant, I'm doing my best to weigh the pros and cons of automating this process without Apex (if possible), or handing it over to the clients and having them do two data loads manually. The latter option is rarely the best in a scenario like this and the former doesn't look like it is worth the time, so Apex seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Would it be useful, on the first load, to only load the fields the two objects share and also establish the relationship through the Process builder, then do a second data load on the Application object to add the rest of the required data?

Comment: Honestly I would just split the csv with Python, myself. Wouldn't be hard to do in Excel, either. Load the parent first. then the child. Have them send the csv if it's too much effort. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. you can able to do it in a Single Data load provided
 ***vast majority of the information*** fields data you can capture at contact level (May be you can remove the these fields from front end).

1.Create a  Process Builder on Contact To create a child record which is Applicant.

Regarding the Recordtypeid you can use reference or a Value when you are Mapping the Fields

Comment: Just to make sure I'm describing my question correctly, the Contact record must be the parent in this relationship, and the Application must be the child.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that I would need to load all of the information to invisible fields on the Contact object, and then pass that information to the Application object via the Process Builder, right?

Comment: @evankincade That is the basic approach if you want to pursue this implementation strategy.

Comment: @evankincade... Yes.